# Can anyone give advice related to growing an Ayurvedic Herb Garden?

Tags: herbs, organic

I'm currently growing a few herbs and spices in pots on my terrace using Natural/Organic gardening techniques. Turmeric, Basil (Tulsi), Lemon-Grass, Omum are few herbs.

I'd like to transition to growing **Ayurvedic herbs** on a larger scale in future in **Southern India**. The best thing is to ask people who've already got full-blown herb-farms.

1. What problems/solutions did you experience in **real-life** situations?
2. Do you need totally different techniques when going from a terrace garden to a farm?

Any pointers to people/websites/books/resources to help transition from being a weekend hobby terrace-gardener to growing herbs on a farm would be most welcome.

Comment: You should check out a short book called "[*Ghrelu Bagichi*](http://issuu.com/khetivirasatmission/docs/ghrelu_bagichi?mode=window&viewMode=doublePage)" from the **[Kheti Virasat Mission](http://www.khetivirasatmission.org)**. This is basically an organization which promotes natural farming in Punjab, and their book was very good & beneficial for me. They are in Punjab, so the book is written in Punjabi. Since you are in southern India, I'm not sure if you will get something useful from it, but you can check it out at least. There are also many videos on YouTube, such as "one man one cow one pl

Answer (score 2):

1. What are other good herbs to grow in pots?

   - A lot of then, but first of all I would as you what herbs you like. And of this set which you can plant with the wheather where you live.
   - you can plan Mint, pasley, sage, oregano.... a lot of then but try to see how much light and moisture you have. Some of then (like dill) grows a lot, so you need to see if your pots are big enough
2. Do's/Don'ts or advice from people who already have full-blown herb-gardens on problems/solutions would be welcome.

   - Control the plage (mainly slug and special flies) and some deseases (powdery mildew), because if you loose the control you will have to throw your herbs away
3. Do herbs scale well from a terrace garden to a small plot of land?

   - Usualy they grow in pots as fine as in lands, and some of them can't grows betters in places with shadow than directly with the sun.

Hope I could help you. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm actually looking for people/books/resources to help transition from being a weekend hobby terrace-gardener to growing herbs on a farm. I've updated my question to be more clear on this.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion on slugs/flies/mildew. It would really useful if you could give more specific advice or links to resources. Can't upvote your answer as I'm a newbie on this site.

Comment: about books I can say that a good one is "Grow your own food" by Richard Gianfranceco, but it doesn't talk only about pots, it says about how to have an orchard, and etc...